# Inappbrowser doesn´t work in a Sencha Touch webapp

Tags: objective-c, cordova, sencha-touch

I am having problems with the inappbrowser cordova implementation, I have changed a thousand times depending of the post but continues without works.
Here my configuration in the config.xml

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    <plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
</plugins>
```

Here my JS configuration

```
if(Ext.os.deviceType == "Tablet" && Ext.os.name == "iOS"){
   window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

Here my Sencha code included in the controller (I don´t know if could be relevant..)

```
control: {
        'attachmentsList': {
            itemtap: 'onTapOpenUrl'
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I have been searching in all forums in the world (of course including this) and I don´t find the solution.

Any solution in the playground??

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution of this tricky issue...

Steps:

1º Go to CDVWebViewDelegate.m (in the CordovaLib classes)

2º In the line 209 add this code:

```
//add below code....
if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",request.URL] rangeOfString:@"file"].location== NSNotFound)
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
return NO;
}
// End code
```

I think this code can be very useful because in other posts I found the "typical" solution with the `window.open(url, "_blank", "location=yes");` but for me didn´t work.